# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am learning React Typescript, and I have defined a onChange event props. But getting below mentioned errror.

Input.tsx

```
type InputProps ={
    value: string,
    handleChange: (event:React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>)=> void;
}

export const Input = (props: InputProps) =>{
    const handleInputChange:React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> =(event)=>{
        console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
        props.handleChange(event.currentTarget.value)//Having issue in this line
    }
    return <input type="text" value={props.value} onChange={handleInputChange} />
}
```

App.tsx

```
<Input handleChange={value=> console.log(value)} value=""/>
```

Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEventHandler'.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `handleChange` as a function that accepts an event object:

```typescript
type InputProps ={
    value: string,
    handleChange: (event:React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>)=> void;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

But you're trying to pass it a string:

```typescript
props.handleChange(event.currentTarget.value)//Having issue in this line
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Either define the function so it accepts a string, or pass it the event object. I would do the former, define it so that it accepts a string:

```typescript
type InputProps = {
    value: string;
    handleChange: (value: string) => void;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgEkA7MAVxgAUcwBnOAXjgBvcnDFwAbigA2rJAC44PGFGBMA5hXFwAFiiYATaUgDCejQrgAKKbMvLVGgJQCAfJIjADFAPQ+4gEhEQcEhoQEAepFR0VHkAL4U5EgAHpCwcGgQTMqMLOwC1mDcPIrMbJzFLvzuItqZ2fDmRkhl7Gb66pbI6DAAdO0WAKISSEwwABL6zVAAPOMAKgCyADKtMIPGIKMw7oJWSCNjVTWi2uL1PBDGvdIQ6vuHfWisUERj8yhQnX22ck5aZzERQgvF6TWMA06D22vWer22Hy+SB+Mj+pDgfkmEjU6jgwB4PDkeKYcBgOnxcGkaiQpzECVpcCIMBeJJmanKpNoSH4+BgKRg+EkqO5QmBoN+SDicCykJF4JaeRgsqlPlcFHp5Bma10Uwh5k6-CENmFxwyWUu11u9wlTilEp5gtVpCAA)

But if you prefer, pass it the event object:

```typescript
type InputProps = {
    value: string;
    handleChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};

// ...

props.handleChange(event);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
```

Notice that the `event` parameter is `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, not `ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgEkA7MAVxgAUcwBnOAXjgBvcnDFwAbigA2rJAC44PGFGBMA5hXFwAFiiYATaUgDCejQrgAKJBKRMYi5OhgA6M-vVIAonYcAeAAkAFQBZABlmNhhvYxB7GAA+AEoBRMkIYAMKAHocuEAkIiLiktKyooA9Kuqa2rr6+vIAXwpyJAAPSFg4NAgmZUYWdgFrMG4eRSj2LgheVP50kW1e-vhzIyQpmA8LJ2I3Ha9fBMD9DaggsMihmLiE9MEbPxh5xdFtcRWeCGNXaQh1E8Eq40KwoEQHMEUFAvG4pLIkMktB8xGNZjxXOtjIckECHEjyHlCuUSSTau8xC0KXAiDAwUw4P41NE4DQ6Px8DAOjB8JIZHJ+EI0bxXPC5E04H0cYKsZsbjiJTlEhQqeR-FtdGdseYvIKrGLEWken1vr9-oCDckJQaObylaQgA)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is `props.handleChange(event)` as in the type definition, you already said that the argument `event` is gonna be of type `React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>` but as you are using `event.target.value` which is in fact a `string`, so you are getting an error.